# Process management in TempleOS: listing and killing processes?

Tags: task-manager, kill, tasks, ps, templeos

TempleOS has different processes, according to [`docs/Glossary.DD.Z`](https://templeos.holyc.xyz/Wb/Doc/Glossary.html),

> There is no distinction between task, process or thread.  The Fs segment reg is kept pointing to the current task's CTask.  There is only one window per task, and only Core0 tasks can have windows.  Each task has a code and data heap so memory is returned when it dies.  Each task has a hash symbol table.
>
> Since there is not friendly disk sharing and all tasks have the same address map, it might be accurate to call TempleOS, "multi-thread/single-process". You run a single application process on Core0 and it can create threads on the same core or others.  **If you run multiple processes, it should be safe, but one process will wait until another completely finishes a long disk access**

From that we *can* run multiple processes, and I am guessing when we run an application, such as a game, that game runs as its own process until completion and then gives back control to the terminal. How can we from the terminal get a list of processes, or kill them? I don't see any documentation on process management?

What is the TempleOS way to run `ps` and `kill`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TempleOS equivalent of

- `ps` is [`TaskRep;`](https://templeos.holyc.xyz/Wb/Adam/TaskRep.html)
- `kill` is [`Kill(task);`](https://templeos.holyc.xyz/Wb/Kernel/KTask.html)

You can see a screen sot of `TaskRep()` here, `#0` is the Adam task.

[image]